# div's height fit container div's height with auto-scroll

Tags: css, html, css-tables

I got a problem with CSS styling of a page.
Basically I have a div that will be used as a dialog in which I'd like to organize the content in 2 columns: the first one could contain a long list of elements, and should be scrollable, the second one should be small and in a fixed position. Thus I don't want all the dialog content to be crollable but just the half of it.
I put toghether an example [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw8WK/1/) in case you need to do some try... the code is:

CSS

```
#container {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 200px;
}
#main {
    display: table;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    height: 200px;
}
#row{
    display: table-row;
    height: 200px;
}
#leftPanel{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
#rightPanel{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="row">
            <div id="leftPanel"> <!-- This one should be scrollable -->
                <!-- Long list of element here-->
            </div>
            <div id="rightPanel">
                <div style="height: 50px;">
                    Something here
                </div>
                <div style="height: 50px;">
                    Something else here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

How can I get leftPanel to be scrollable?
As you can see I tried even setting a fixed height of every component of the CSS table, but without any result... what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zw8WK/10/

Using `overflow-y: scroll` or alternately `overflow : scroll`

Now if you need the height of the left column to be some kind of variable height it might be more tricky, here I am setting it to the height of the parent container.

Comment: Thanks. Actually yes, the left columns should be smaller than the container div, this was just a simplyfied example... but I think I can figure it out from myself... or at least trying, before making a new question on SO ;)

Comment: Is it possible to do without setting height to leftPanel (it should be inherited from container) ?